# Print something after found the xxx in 'elif xxx in line' only the second time

Tags: python

I want to print "end scan" at the end of line when "binary [4]:" appears for the second time only.

```
for line in infile:
  with open('convert-profile.txt', "a") as f1:
    if "index" in line:
        f1.write("\n"+line)
    elif "scan start time" in line:
        f1.write(line)  
    elif "binary: [4]" in line:
        f1.write(line)
    elif "binary: [4]" in line: *for the second time after the same index only*
        f1.write(line+"end scan")
```

Is it possible to do this in if-loop by python?

---

infile is text file which has information line by line

```
index: 1
scan start time: 0.01
binary1
binary [4]: 10 2 3 7
binary2
binary [4]: 11 11 34 12
index: 2
scan start time: 0.03 ...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have an outer variable keep track of the amount of times "binary: [4]" appeared in the file.

Try:

```
cnt = 0
for line in infile:
    with open('convert-profile.txt', "a") as f1:
        if "index" in line:
            f1.write("\n"+line)
        elif "scan start time" in line:
            f1.write(line)  
        elif "binary [4]:" in line and cnt != 1:
             f1.write(line)
             cnt += 1
        elif "binary [4]:" in line and cnt == 1:
             f1.write(line+"end scan")
```

**EDIT**
I noticed the input file was formatted `binary [4]:` instead of `binary: [4]` in your code, so I assume you meant to use the former.